# SP 2013 - Set Var to Lookup Value via SPServices

Tags: javascript, spservices

I need to get the value of a lookup control on a display form and store it in a variable.  I was thinking I could use SPServices to accomplish this, but (unfortunately) I don't have much experience with it.

I also need to do the same on the edit form, but also recapture the value if it changes.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use javascript to get the value of the element containing the field value.  jQuery may make this easier if you're new to JS.

Comment: What are you going to do with the value stored in a variable? Can you give us a few more details about your project?

Comment: I’m planning to create a cookie and pass the variable to it.  The cookie will be used to pass the value to a hidden field in another form.  In theory, this hidden field will be used to filter a lookup in this second form via spservices.

Comment: The big picture goal is to filter a lookup in a child form based on a lookup value in the parent form.  There is a relationship between the parent and child lookups that I’m hoping to leverage as a filter.

Comment: You probably want to use SPUtility.js not SPServices.js. https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I was able to store the parent lookup value and pass it to a new cookie using the following ... Thanks for suggesting SPUtility.js!

[image]

Now for the next step!